# Cant see Development mode and Cant post question in Dev Forums on SFDC

Tags: chrome

Ever have one of those moments when you think you have entered the Twilight Zone?

I attempted to have a look at some VF code so I enabled Dev Mode. Could not see the tab at the bottom of the screen. Cleared Chrome Cache (Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit) and tried again - no luck. Tried to post a question in the Community - got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined throws at https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/:1283:42

Is anyone else having this difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to have a quick look at code I'd highly recommend [aside.io](http://aside.io) over dev mode.